# GAE - Wordpress Akismet error

Tags: google-app-engine, wordpress, akismet

I am having a problem in activating Akismet plugin on GAE. When I opened https://my-blog.appspot.com/wp-admin/plugins.php?page=akismet-key-config&show=enter-api-key, I got this error:

> There was a problem connecting to the Akismet server. Please check
>   your server configuration.

The following is the GAE log,

```
2013-11-02 10:15:55.761 /wp-admin/plugins.php?page=akismet-key-config&show=enter-api-key 200 360ms 19kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
218.212.43.178 – - [02/Nov/2013:10:15:55 -0700] “GET /wp-admin/plugins.php?page=akismet-key-config&show=enter-api-key HTTP/1.1″ 200 19070 – “Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36″ “wp-dot-ms-cloud-blog.appspot.com” ms=360 cpu_ms=303 cpm_usd=0.002131 app_engine_release=1.8.6 instance=00c61b117c65c8b3d0eb64b28603f5d885d3b793
```

I wrote about all issues that I have in **[this post](http://michaelsync.net/2013/10/27/migrating-the-existing-blog-to-google-app-engine-php-runtime-is-not-that-simple)**. Is there anyone who activated the Akismet plugin and ran Wordpress successfully on GAE?

- I am **NOT** trying to send traffic to my blog from StackOverflow. I already posted the error message and log here so you can figure out the issue without clicking on my link. But one guy from Google commented that Akismet should be working fine in my post so I am posting the link in case anyone wants to follow up and see the screenshot in the comment section.

Comment: Just brainstorming. If the UA has something to do with it, Akismet has a [filter for it](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/akismet/tags/2.5.9/akismet.php#L144). And there are a series of [filters in WP_Http class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/class-http.php#L81) that you could try to tweak. I'd look specially into `http_request_args`.

Comment: Thanks man.. Akismet using wp_remote_post or fsockopen that uses UrlFetch so it supposed to work.. maybe. it doesn't use. I tried enabled debugging but can't see any log..

Comment: Ha. fsockopen is disabled.

Comment: added the log, it is using wp_remote_post only. The error message that I got is "0: Unable to find the socket transport "tcp" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?" and GAE doesn't support tcp outbound. strange.

Comment: Does “wp_remote_post” makes TCP outbound socket?

Comment: I am looking at http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/class-http.php.. seems like it doesn't use file_get_contents..

Comment: I've just read that Akismet is forbidden in Germany for privacy issues... What if you try [Antispam Bee](http://wordpress.org/plugins/antispam-bee/)?

Comment: I'm now running into the "0: Unable to find..." error after upgrading WP from v3.6.1 to v3.7.1. I'm seeing the issue trying to active JetPack with Wordpress.com which was working just fine prior to the upgrade.

Comment: Steve, Did you manage to activate Akismet?